# Adding CASE or similar statements to _productCollection->AddAttributeToSort() in Magento

Tags: php, sql, magento

I'm trying to edit how my products are ordered in the Magento products list once a user has selected the price drop-down to display the cheapest first. This shows the prices with 0 on the top when listed, shown as:

```
Product 4 £0
Product 5 £0
Product 1 £50
Product 2 £65
Product 3 £80
```

At the moment it would show as this:

```
Product 1 £50
Product 2 £65
Product 3 £80
Product 4 £0
Product 5 £0
```

I have managed to edit the `_getProductCollection()` method inside the file `/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List.php` (don't worry I've copied to local) and added these few lines:

```
$orderFilterType = $this->getRequest()->getParam('order');
$dirFilterType = $this->getRequest()->getParam('dir');

if( isset( $orderFilterType ) && $orderFilterType == 'price' && isset( $dirFilterType ) && $dirFilterType == 'asc' ) {

$this->_productCollection = $layer->getProductCollection();

$order_field = 'new_price_for_sort';

$this->_productCollection->getSelect()->joinLeft( array('a' => 'catalog_product_entity_price'), 'a.product_id=e.entity_id AND a.attibute_id=PRICE or SPECIAL PRICE ATTRIBUTE ID', array('new_price_for_sort' => new Zend_Db_Expr('IF(a.value > 0,1, 0)') ) );

$this->_productCollection->getSelect()->reset(Zend_Db_Select::ORDER);

$dir = 'DESC'; 

if ( !$this->_productCollection->isEnabledFlat() ) { 

$this->_productCollection->setOrder($order_field, $dir); 

} else {

$this->_productCollection->getSelect()->order($order_field . ' ' . $dir); 

}

$this->_productCollection->setOrder('price', $dir);


} else { $this->_productCollection = $layer->getProductCollection(); }
```

This means that anytime somebody selects the price, asc filter from the drop-down then it adds the price sort using `addAttributeToSort` which works fine but I can't work out how to get the 0 priced products to go to the bottom using this.

In SQL I'd usually use a CASE statement such as:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY CASE price WHEN 0 then 1 ELSE 0 END, price
```

However I have no idea how I would implement something like this in my code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I have told previously:

```
 $order_field = 'new_price_for_sort';
 $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('a' => 'catalog_product_entity_price'), // or here you will need Price Index Table Name if you have Groupped or configurable products. But need to remember that non-simple products always have 0 price and MAX_PRICE/MIN_PRICE should be used then 
 'a.product_id=e.entity_id AND a.attibute_id=PRICE or SPECIAL PRICE ATTRIBUTE ID', // or here you will not require attribute_id condition if you are using INDEX TABLE
 array('new_price_for_sort' => new Zend_Db_Expr('IF(a.value > 0,1, 0)'), // which mean that in new field we will have price if it's not 0, and will have big integer is real price is zero. 
                    ));
            }
// now we are reseting current order by
            $collection->getSelect()->reset(Zend_Db_Select::ORDER);

// and creating new order by new field, but with saving direction of order
$dir = 'DESC'; // as we need to have products WITH price first, and after that WITHOUT price
            if (!$collection->isEnabledFlat()) {
                $collection->setOrder($order_field, $dir);
            } else {
                $collection->getSelect()->order($order_field . ' ' . $dir);
            }
//and now add Order by price with keeping direction that user have choosed 
$collection->setOrder('price', $arr['dir']);
```

Comment: I saw your previous answer however how does this work within what I am doing? Where would I fit this in my code?

Comment: try to put my code between  `if( isset( $orderFilterType ) && $orderFilterType == 'price' && isset( $dirFilterType ) && $dirFilterType == 'asc' ) {`
and  `} else { `

Comment: I'm struggling to find how this affects the value of $this->_productCollection which needs to be returned. I get parsing syntax errors when simply placing this between my if statement

Comment: here is your code merged with mine  ` $orderFilterType = $this->getRequest()->getParam('order');
$dirFilterType = $this->getRequest()->getParam('dir');

if( isset( $orderFilterType ) && $orderFilterType == 'price' && isset( $dirFilterType ) && $dirFilterType == 'asc' ) {

$this->_productCollection = $layer->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToSort( 'price', 'DESC' );


} else { 

$this->_productCollection = $layer->getProductCollection();

}`

Answer (score 0):

here is your code merged with mine

```
$orderFilterType = $this->getRequest()->getParam('order');
$dirFilterType = $this->getRequest()->getParam('dir');

if( isset( $orderFilterType ) && $orderFilterType == 'price' && isset( $dirFilterType ) && $dirFilterType == 'asc' ) {

$this->_productCollection = $layer->getProductCollection();
$order_field = 'new_price_for_sort';
$this->_productCollection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('a' => 'catalog_product_entity_price'), // or here you will need Price Index Table Name if you have Groupped or configurable products. But need to remember that non-simple products always have 0 price and MAX_PRICE/MIN_PRICE should be used then 
'a.product_id=e.entity_id AND a.attibute_id=PRICE or SPECIAL PRICE ATTRIBUTE ID', // or here you will not require attribute_id condition if you are using INDEX TABLE
array('new_price_for_sort' => new Zend_Db_Expr('IF(a.value > 0,1, 0)'), // which mean that in new field we will have price if it's not 0, and will have big integer is real price is zero.
));
    }
// now we are reseting current order by
$this->_productCollection->getSelect()->reset(Zend_Db_Select::ORDER);
// and creating new order by new field, but with saving direction of order
$dir = 'DESC'; // as we need to have products WITH price first, and after that WITHOUT price
if (!$this->_productCollection->isEnabledFlat()) {
    $this->_productCollection->setOrder($order_field, $dir);
  } else {
    $this->_productCollection->getSelect()->order($order_field . ' ' . $dir);
 }
//and now add Order by price with keeping direction that user have choosed 
$this->_productCollection->setOrder('price', $arr['dir']);
} else { 
    $this->_productCollection = $layer->getProductCollection();
}
```

Comment: Hi Tagan... Thanks for this, I will check this tomorrow when I'm back on my computer with the site on and let you know how I get on... Seriously, thanks for all your help so far...

Comment: I've just tried this but its throwing exception errors on the site when I try to order by price asc, trouble is the log part is too long to paste here

Comment: Ive updated my question with the exact code ive used above in case it helps you to see if ive made a mistake with it somewhere